# How do I run a function on each post in my list view and pass a boolean variable into my html?

Tags: python, django

#### My html

```
{% if post.is_liked %}
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
{% else %}
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
{% endif %}
```

#### My views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(created__range=['2020-03-01', '2020-03-31'])
    template_name = 'main/problems.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-created']

    def get_liked(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=post.kwargs.get('username'))
        if post.likes.filter(username=user).exists():
            post.annotate(is_liked=True)
        else:
            post.annotate(is_liked=False)
```

Even if I set both conditionals to return true my html does not read `is_liked` as true.

Comment: Your `for` loop will simply run when you construct the class, and furthermore you will simply define a function (multiple times), not execute the function. Finally note that this should alter the attribute of a `Post`, not just a general object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop will simply run when you construct the class, and furthermore you will simply define a function (multiple times), not execute the function. Finally note that this should alter the attribute of a `Post`, not just a general object.

You can annotate your queryset with:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef
from app.models import Post, Like

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'main/problems.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-created']
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Post.objects.filter(
            created__range=['2020-03-01', '2020-03-31']
        ).annotate(
            is_liked=Exists(Like.objects.filter(
                user_id=self.request.user.pk, post_id=OuterRef('pk')
            ))
        )
```

The `user_id` and `post_id` might have different names, depending on how you constructed your `Like` model.

Then in the template, you can check the `is_liked` attribute of your `Post` objects:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.is_liked %}
        …
    {% else %}
        …
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I do not have a like model. It is necessary for what I am trying to do?